# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object in binarysearch python

Tags: python, binary-search

```
  def binarysearch (a,x):

  low=0
  high=len(a)-1
   while(low<=high):
     mid=math.ceil((high+low)/2)
     if(x==a[mid]):
         return(mid)
         exit()
      elif(x<=a[mid]):
         high=mid-1
         b= binarysearch(a,x)
         return(b)
         exit()
        elif (x>=a[mid]):
       low=mid+1
        m=binarysearch(a,x)
     return(m)
     exit()
    else:
      c=("Number not found")
      return c
      exit()
```

`i am getting these errors:

```
File "E:\Phd\6th sem\pythonProject\binarynew.py", line 45, in <module>
pos=binarysearch(a,x)
File "E:\Phd\6th sem\pythonProject\binarynew.py", line 31, in binarysearch
b= binarysearch(a,x)
File "E:\Phd\6th sem\pythonProject\binarynew.py", line 31, in binarysearch
b= binarysearch(a,x)
File "E:\Phd\6th sem\pythonProject\binarynew.py", line 31, in binarysearch
b= binarysearch(a,x)
[Previous line repeated 995 more times]
File "E:\Phd\6th sem\pythonProject\binarynew.py", line 23, in binarysearch
   high=len(a)-1
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Process finished with exit code 1

please resolve thanks

trying to implement binary search on the given `array a=[10,20,30,40,50]

Comment: Please fix your indentation to make the code readable. Regarding the error: You are recursing too many times. For an array of length 5, this means there is a bug in the code and the array is probably not shrinking (being trimmed) when being passed back up to the recursive function.

Comment: The logic is off when you're in either - ```x<=a[mid])```  you need to pass the lower and higher bound to the *function* itself.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a recursive approach to a binary search